# Initiating an outbound conference call using Twilio Functions

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-functions, twilio-node

I do not see any documentation in creating a conference call in twilio functions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initiating an outbound call using Twilio Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63996304/initiating-an-outbound-call-using-twilio-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start with something like this:

```js
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  
  // create response object (to return TwiML)
  let response = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  
  // dial a conference room
  const dial = response.dial();
  dial.conference('Some Room');
  
  // for debug
  console.log(response.toString());
  
  // return conference TwiML
  return callback(null, response);

};
```

This is similar with how a forward call Twilio function would be, but instead you "dial" a conference room, not a number.

Configure your Twilio number so it runs the function when a call comes in.

With the new Twilio functions interface, you'll need to create a service before you create a function. If you want to see the logs, you'll need to togle "Enable live logs" to see the `console.log(response.toString());`.

[image]

---

You can get more inspiration from the docs for Node.js here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/conference

Comment: I've added a picture, the button is on the bottom right, before the red "Clear".

Comment: I can't see it. I'm using Functions(Classic).

Comment: For classic, the logs also show when your function is executed. They appear at the bottom, in a pane under the editor.

Comment: How can I add participants to the current conference? Should I use statusCallback and create a Twiml Function to handle that callback? For example, I want to call a number and add that number to the current conference.

Comment: I have not tried it but, yes, it could work. Once they answer serve them the TwiML for the conference. Also take a look at this https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/conference-participant-resource#create-a-participant-agent-conference-only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221852/discussion-between-martinii-and-alex-baban).